# How to make joints for 3D printing?

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-printing

I have a hand that I want to make movable. I don't really understand how to make joints with blender. This is for 3D printing so they need to be outside not just armatures. I think I may need to cut the model where I want the joints to be and make a hinge type joint using cubes but I don't really know if that is right or how to do those things.

Comment: I'd start by examining existing 3D models if hand joints for printing, like in the open hand project (http://www.openhandproject.org/), and you might want to do some thorough modeling tutorials to learn how to make complex shapes. A good place to find professional tuts is Blender Cookie (https://cgcookie.com/course/mesh-modeling-fundamentals/).

Comment: @TLousky when I clicked on the link you provided the screen read .....  Access every post, every video, every resource, every source file...starting at $23/mo! ... Is that the correct link?

Comment: Yes, CG cookie is an education website with some courses free and others not free (subscription based). You can find other free sources online but I don't know a more organized and thorough source.

Comment: this really depends on what printing method you're using. and yes, you can make joints in blender, there are just so many methods.

Comment: Take a look at this model: http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:584405 It has multiple prints of a really solid ball joint. I've printed it myself and it works great

Answer (score 0):

I think the quickest and probably easiest thing for you to do is as you said cut the joints in Blender and instead of making a hinge system make a pin system. So basically what i am saying is have like 2 parts with 2 holes which align in the right position and then just slide a 3D printed pin/Cylinder into it. This would allow you to move along a certain axis. However if you wanted something that could be rotated fully then i would suggest a ball and clasp type system. Now this could be trickier for the fingers but would almost certainly work for the hand to arm joint.

Hope this helps!